# Google App Script spreadsheed parseInt/Number()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to generate a simple but unique ID for every new row from the 6th row. I start adding data from B6 and I need to generate an ID in A6. Even if a new row is inserted it should work. The problem is that it show #NUM!

Yet I've tried parseInt(x, 10), parseInt(x), Number(x) and either were working.

My code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet       = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var edditRow    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var edditColumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  var column0     = sheet.getRange(edditRow, 1, 1, 2);
  var oValues     = column0.getValues();

  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var properties     = userProperties.getProperty('id');
  var id;

  if (properties ==  null) {
    userProperties.setProperty('id', '1'); 

    if ((oValues[0][0] == '') && (edditRow > 5)  && (oValues[0][1] != '')) {
      id = Number(properties);

      sheet.getRange(edditRow, 1, 1, 1).setValue(id);
      id += 1;
      userProperties.setProperty('id', id);
    } 
  } else {
    id = Number(properties);

    Logger.log(id);

    if ((oValues[0][0] == '') && (edditRow > 5)  && (oValues[0][1] != '')) {
      sheet.getRange(edditRow, 1, 1, 1).setValue(id);
      id += 1;
      userProperties.setProperty('id', id);
    }  
  }
}
```

[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS5Io.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate please? What do you mean by "if a new row is inserted" I can't really get it to display any error. Even when copying a row from another sheet with a value in column B column A gets populated, which is what I assume you want?

Comment: By insert I mean even if a row added to the bottom or a row inserted between 2 other rows the script should generate a new unique ID. It only means that I need a global variant which I have in the code. The problem is:
 `sheet.getRange(edditRow, 1, 1, 1).setValue(id);  ` sets the cell but it shows #NUM! instead of a number.

Comment: there are logic errors. uses properties even when not set

Comment: Could you be more specific please @ZigMandel?
properties will contain 'null' if ID doesn't exist.

Comment: search for "properties" after ` if (properties ==  null) `

Comment: I get it! Thanks a lot! Somehow it felt normal to setProperty will set my variable. What a fail. Cheers mate! Since its an onEdit trigger shouldn't be problem only at the 1st edit? Shouldn't it work at the 2nd edit?

Comment: Not sure what was the problem but after clearing my user properties it worked well plus I added what you @ZigMandel suggested. Thanks for your help if you post and answer I'll give the check mark. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you check for `if (properties ==  null)` and then use the undefined `properties` var a few lines into the `if` which would cause an invalid value.